# Irreducibility of a Polynomial over Q

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

How do I show that for any odd prime $p$ the polynomial $f(x)=x^p-9$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Sorry everyone for the edit.

Comment: Try to substitute $x + a$ for appropriate $a$ and apply Eisenstein's criterion. You only have to pick $a$ such that the constant term is divisible by $p$ but not by $p^2$.

Comment: Suggestion: to avoid confusion it would be best not to use $p$ for two different things in the same question.  Maybe write $f(x)=x^p-9$.

Comment: [Newton's polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Advanced_explanation) should work here. Over 3-adics all the zeros of $p(x)$ have 3-adic (exponential) value $2/p$. For a product of a subset of any $s$ of them to be an integer, we need $2s/p$ to be an integer, i.e. we need $s=p$.